# Replace string from findstr command output

Tags: windows, string, replace, cmd

I successfully managed to seek strings in a long list of files with `findstr`. I'm redirecting `findstr`'s output to different text files, however I need to get rid of the starting part of the output line which contains also the reference of the source file. The base is the example below

```
echo testtest > testing.txt
findstr 'test' *.txt > output.txt //output is 'testing.txt:testtest'
```

I need to do something like this instead

```
echo testtest > testing.txt
findstr 'test' *.txt | *something* > output.txt //output is 'testtest'
```

CAVEAT:
I can use only the standard CMD commands, I can't install new software on the target machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%i in ('findstr "test" *.txt') do (
  echo %%j
) >> output.txt
```

Beware that all input files **must** have a trailing newline, otherwise the first match of the current file might get appended to the last match of the previous file if that match was in the last line:

```
testtestFOO.TXT:something test other
```

Comment: +1, Good catch with regard to the CR/LF issue :-) I've got a solution for that in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14489995/1012053)

Comment: Can there really be an issue with CRLF though? You are printing the results with `echo`, which *always* appends CRLF, does it not?

Comment: @AndriyM - Most definitely! The problem occurs long before ECHO. FINDSTR against multiple files can concantenate lines if the last line of a file matches and is missing CR/LF. When FINDSTR prints the matching line, it prints the binary image of the line, including line terminators. FINDSTR does not append its own CR/LF if the matching line is missing it.

Comment: @dbenham: Ah, the temptation to look clever without verifying things! Thanks for setting me right.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that solves the CR/LF issue that Ansgar Wiechers identified in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488418/1012053).

I use a FOR loop to iterate all the files and run FINDSTR on each individual file. I echo a blank line between each file. At the end I use one more FINDSTR to remove any unwanted blank lines.

```
@echo off
>"output.txt" (
  for %%F in (*.txt) do (
    findstr "test" "%%F"
    (echo()
  )
)
findstr . "output.txt" >"output.txt.new"
move /y "output.txt.new" "output.txt" >nul
type output.txt
```

Comment: This works, but in my context I am sure that no matches will be in the last line and I prefer a one liner program. However many thanks (and +1)

Answer (score 0):

You should use PowerShell (`powershell.exe`) in order to develop the script you need.
The documentation available by command line is really exaustive:

```
PS > help about
```

if you need more: [Is there a Language Reference Manual for PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331829/is-there-a-language-reference-manual-for-powershell)

Comment: Thanks pal, but I really need CMD. How would the resulting ps script be?

Answer (score -1):

On Linux systems, you can use `awk` like for the following command:

```
cat output.txt | awk 'match($0,":"){print substr($0,RSTART+1)}'
```